# XFCE Desktop error at uninstalling, "xubuntu-default-settings" missing

Tags: 16.04, apt, xfce, purge

How do I get rid of XFCE without having to install "xubuntu-default-settings"? Since that package can't be installed in my 16.04 system, how can i purge "xubuntu-desktop"?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you want to continue using Xubuntu without XFCE? Please explain.

Comment: no, i just use XCFE with ubuntu, not xubuntu